# Xpath/PHP: Issues matching a class substring

Tags: php, xpath

I'm trying to match a simple substring in a p element's class attribute but getting errors:

```
$pElements = $crawler2
  ->filter(
 "p[contains(@class, 'price')]"); 
  // Expected operator, but <delimiter "(" at 10> found

  // "descendant-or-self::p[contains(@class, 'price')"); 
  // Unexpected pseudo-element "::p" found not at the end of a selector
```

The prefix on the 2nd (commented) selection statement I got from here: https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/css_selector.html

I'm using this library with Goute in PHP for web scraping.

From the errors (in the server error log) it looks like the xpath is bad. Can anyone see the mistake?

Comment: `Unexpected pseudo-element "::p" found`... Are you sure your `filter` function performs an XPath query?

Comment: No, that is likely the cause then. Scraping is new to me so I will be more careful about that, thanks

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you don't have closing `]` bracket
Try this string: `"p[contains(@class, 'price')]"` in `filter` function

Comment: You are right, I will fix the post now. I copied/pasted your revised code and still get: `[Tue Apr 09 07:02:53.367451 2019] [php7:notice] [pid 8338] [client 127.0.0.1:59068] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Symfony\\Component\\CssSelector\\Exception\\SyntaxErrorException: Expected operator, but <delimiter "(" at 10> found.`